# how i can duplicate div when click in link by javascript

Tags: javascript

hello all i`m good php developer not learn js yet..... my problem is
i have div

```
<div id="test1">

</div>
<a href="">add div</a>
```

i want when click in add div link, dublicte div and change number in id to be test2 , test3, unlimited
like the example

```
<div id="test1">

</div>
<div id="test2">

</div>
<div id="test3">

</div>
```

Comment: With straight Javascript or using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery this can easily be accomplished with the following:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#div-creator').click(function(){
       var numberOfDivs = $('.testClass').length;
       $('<div id="test' + numberOfDivs + '" class="testClass">hi</div>').appendTo('body');
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="test1" class="testClass"></div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="div-creator">Add Div</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Demo can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/4eDkJ/1/

Comment: oky if i want set limit ex i want limit to be 4 thats meaning i can increase more than 4 divs

Comment: Since it would be difficult to get the updated code in here you can check the extended example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4eDkJ/2/ it shows how to add at max 4 divs. Since you marked this as an answer please consider up-voting it :P

Answer (score 0):

Get the original div with document.getElementById()

Then create a new div with document.createElement('div')

Then loop on all the attributes for the first div, setting each one on the second div. Put in a case for element.getAttribute('id') and increment the number before you set it

When your new div is done, do originaldiv.parentNode.appendChild(newdiv)

Comment: thx but i said im not learn js yet so i dont know wht meaning of document.getElementById().....